# Why Filter of Dynamic variable in Izpack does not work

Tags: java, regex, izpack, dynamic-variables

i have a filter for my dynamic variable in installer.xml file but it does not work. I would like to replace "\" with "/".

```
<dynamicvariables>
     <variable name="plugin.dir.parsed" value="$INSTALL_PATH\myfolder">
      <filters>
        <regex regexp="[/\\]+" replace="/" global="true" />
     </filters>
  </variable>
</dynamicvariables>
```

Comment: You have no closing `</dynamicvariables>` tag and unbalanced double quotes for `value` attribute. Should be `value="$INSTALL_PATH\myfolder"`

Comment: @revo I have </dynamicvariables>  and value="$INSTALL_PATH\myfolder" in code but the filter does not work.

Comment: Then you may clarify what do you mean exactly by *it does not work*.

Comment: It means when i install the application the value of plugin.dir.parsed has \ in it is not replaced by /

Comment: @revo if i put this filter or remove it the value of the plugin.dir.parsed is same.